# How to map Azure share on Raspberry Pi

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, azure-file-share

I'm trying to map an Azure share to my Raspberry Pi. I use the script provided with no modification:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sharename
if [ ! -d "/etc/smbcredentials" ]; then
sudo mkdir /etc/smbcredentials
fi
if [ ! -f "/etc/smbcredentials/storageaccountname.cred" ]; then
    sudo bash -c 'echo "username=storageaccountname" >> /etc/smbcredentials/storageaccountname.cred'
    sudo bash -c 'echo "password=passwordhere" >> /etc/smbcredentials/storageaccountname.cred'
fi
sudo chmod 600 /etc/smbcredentials/storageaccountname.cred

sudo bash -c 'echo "//storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/sharename /mnt/sharename cifs nofail,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/storageaccountname.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30" >> /etc/fstab'
sudo mount -t cifs //storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/xutiazure /mnt/sharename -o credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/storageaccountname.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30
```

The result is this message:

> mount error(115): Operation now in progress
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

The paths, password file and new line in fstab are OK created.

Is there anything else I need to do? I've tried also via mount -a command, but same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed guys,

My ISP is blocking port 445, so it is not working. I've routed it throug a VPN using a different public IP and it worked fine.

Thanks